# redirection in cmd for loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, io-redirection

I want to loop a command 12 times, as:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,12)
```

and run a command with %i be redirected as command input

```
do @php 5.php < %i
```

Of course, the syntax I tried didn't work.
How do I use redirection in cmd for loop ?

Comment: It was my wrong type. I replaced % with @. Sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,12) do @echo %i | php 5.php
```